# issue with table in html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to create this table in html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cluOC.png

I tried this code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="blue" colspan="3">3</th>
    <th class="orange " rowspan="2">2</th>
    <th class="blue" colspan="3">3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cyan" rowspan="4">4</td>
    <td class="cyan">1</td>
    <td class="cyan">1</td>
    <td class="cyan">1</td>
    <td class="cyan">1</td>
    <td class="cyan" rowspan="4">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="orange" colspan="2">2</td>
    <td class="orange" rowspan="3">3</td>
    <td class="orange" colspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cyan" rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td class="cyan" rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td class="cyan" rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td class="cyan" rowspan="2">2</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="green" colspan="2">2</td>
    <td class="orange">1</td>
    <td class="cyan">1</td>
    <td class="orange">1</td>
    <td class="green" colspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

but output is this, one of the rows (penultimate row) is not displayed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmdtl.png

how can I fix it?

Comment: You've added html only. Can you add your css too?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because empty `tr` does not have any height in html DOM.
You can add few CSS height and width properties to get it consistent. i.e-

```
        td {
            min-height: 2em;
            min-width: 2em;
        }
        tr {
            height: 2em;
        }
        .blank-row {
            height: 2em;
        }
```

And then add class `blank-row` to the empty row you have written.

```
 <tr class="blank-row"></tr>
```

It would render properly then:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your 5th "row" isn't really a row - it doesn't contain any cells. Rows don't have any height if there is no content in them. If you created that 5th row only to make the cells above it higher, then you better use `height` settings on the cells.

You can apply a `height`setting to one of the cells in the 4th row which is twice as mhigh as the other ("regular") cells. I did that using the `x` class in the example below.

```css
table {
min-width: 400px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
border: 1px solid #555;
height: 60px;
text-align: center;
}
.x {
height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <th class="blue" colspan="3">3</th>
                <th class="orange " rowspan="2">2</th>
                <th class="blue" colspan="3">3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cyan" rowspan="4">4</td>
                <td class="cyan">1</td>
                <td class="cyan">1</td>
                <td class="cyan">1</td>
                <td class="cyan">1</td>
                <td class="cyan" rowspan="4">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="orange" colspan="2">2</td>
                <td class="orange" rowspan="3">3</td>
                <td class="orange"  colspan="2">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cyan x" rowspan="2">2</td>
                <td class="cyan" rowspan="2">2</td>
                <td class="cyan" rowspan="2">2</td>
                <td class="cyan" rowspan="2">2</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>                

            </tr>
            <tr>                
                <td class="green" colspan="2">2</td>
                <td class="orange">1</td>
                <td class="cyan">1</td>
                <td class="orange">1</td>
                <td class="green" colspan="2">2</td></tr>  

        </table>
```